# AutoHotkey - Iterate through list and send commands between each iteration for data entry

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to use arrays/lists in AHK for some data entry but can't figure out how to iterate properly. I got this code from a similar question which I have been trying:

```
^!G::

VarX=
(
48306237
48306642
48303423
48303612
48303797
)

loop, parse, VarX, \`n,`r
{
    Send, %VarX%
    Send, The next item in the list is
    return
}

return
```

This does indeed iterate through the list, but I am not able to send commands in between.

Currently, this is the output I'm getting:

```
48306237
48306642
48303423
48303612
48303797the next item in the list is
```

How can I make it so the output is as follows?

```
48306237
the next item in the list is
48306642
the next item in the list is
48303423
the next item in the list is
48303612
the next item in the list is
48303797
the next item in the list is
```

Thanks for reading

Solution without added function:

```
VarX=
(
48306237
48306642
48303423
48303612
48303797
)

loop, parse, VarX, `n,`r
{
    SendInput, %A_LoopField%{Enter}
    Send, wait {Enter}
    Sleep, 2000
    Send, OK {Enter} 
}
return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `Loop, parse` the value inside of the loop you're looking for is `A_Loopfield`. It's also useful to make a separate function to clean up your code if it gets overly complex. Here is the correct example usage:

```
VarX=
(
48306237
48306642
48303423
48303612
48303797
)

loop, parse, VarX, \`n,`r
    HandleItem(A_Loopfield)

HandleItem(value)
{
    SendInput % "Item Content: " . value . "`n"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Elliot I finally get it.
Will keep the thing about seperate functions in mind but if anyone would like to do this without an extra function, I managed to do it with the code edited in above.